Support paging keyboard shortcuts in NAtOQ 10k-tools
The paging keybindings are not working for /tools/new-answers-old-questions because the definition of pagerSelector doesn't accomodate for this page. Please add a mapping for pagerSelector for NAtOQ.

As a temporary1 fix, I created a userscript which enables the page navigation using keyboard shortcuts.
On StackApps: NATO(Q) keyboard navigation for pages
Also, the installation section reproduced here for ease of access:

Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
(For instructions how to install userscripts: see the tag wiki here)
Code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name            NATO(Q) keyboard page navigation
// @description     Allow keyboard navigation between different pages (P->N for next / P->P for previous) in the New Answers to Old Questions tool 
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://superuser.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/tools/new-answers-old-questions*
// @version         1.0
// @author          VLAZ
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
  const pager = document.querySelector(".pager");
  
  if (!pager) {
      console.warn("Could not find a pager on the NATO page. The fix for keyboard navigation is not active.")
      return;
  }
  
  pager.classList.add("pager-answers");
})();


1 just for 6-8 weeks
